# Full width of images on foundation orbit slider

Tags: javascript, css, workflow-foundation, orbit

I have problem with width of orbit slider images. My images has 1600px width, but resolution of monitor can be higher - e.g 1680px.
Is it possible to stretch the size of images to 100% of screen (in this example - 1680px)?

My code is standard and looks like this:

```
<div id="featured">
<img src="11.jpg" alt="">
<img src="12.jpg" alt="">
<img src="13.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<script src="js/jquery.foundation.orbit.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function() {
       $("#featured").orbit();
   });
</script>
```

Thanks for any help.

Adrian

Answer (score 1):

its easy just write the orbit code outside the row div that should give you full width.
well in foundation 4 that is.

Comment: Could you please explain with some working example to illustrate better?

Answer (score 0):

- you can get the width of the window using `var imgwidth = window.innerWidth`.
- Set the width property of the images using `$('image_selector').width = imgwidth`.

  $(window).load({

  ```
  var imgwidth = window.innerWidth;
  $('image_selector').width = imgwidth;
  $("#featured").orbit();
  ```

  });

Comment: When images are loading - they have 100% of width, but after loading the width of img is again 1600px

Comment: Sorry - my bad - the images loaded and have the full screen width, but orbit didn't work. I have list of images on site

Answer (score 0):

So is your CSS setup? If you set the width of container (`'#featured'`) and images to 100% it should stretch the image to the width of the window. No need to calculate the width with javascript.